# How do you begin building a firefox addon that alters/replaces the default download feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, download

I want to write a firefox addon that replaces my current default download feature.

I basically just want to add other options to the download window that will allow it to interact with my website.

Where do I get started with this? Does anyone know any code I can get started from? I'd rather not build the entire download from scratch, it seems like a lot of work...

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably start by looking at [the source code to an existing extension which does this](http://downloadstatusbar.mozdev.org/source.html).